# Each of the following graphs represent y=f(x). Find the indicated value for each of the following from the graph.

Tags: calculus

My answers are in red. Did I do these correctly? It seemed too easy. I think bii) might be wrong. If any are wrong i'd appreciate the correct way of doing it, thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The last one doesn't seem correct.$f(9)=8$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are correct except for cii), where either $f(9)=8$ or $f(9)\ d.n.e$.

There is a hole at the coordinate $(9,5)$ and $f(x)$ in this graph resembles $3[\frac{x+3}{4}]-1$ where $[\ ]$ is floor function.

Comment: I can't see why it would be 8, can you explain please?

Comment: Added explanation.